# How to create an standalone GDPR form?

Tags: gdpr, newsletter, privacy

I am using GDPR extension, which provide a popup form after online event signup or contribution.

I would like to provide a standalone form for anonymous user with newsletter signup, privacy, and data policy option that would be integrated with GDPR extension, so that I can trace when the contact last accepted GDPR policy.

Is it possible to do? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be achieved by GDPR webform https://github.com/tapashdatta/webform_gdpr/tree/5.x